# Scroll to a position in page Jquery Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a long form which I want to be scrolled at a point where my gridview is located after a successfull partial postback with an update panel. How can I achieve this with JQuery. I am using update panels in VSS 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the jquery scrollTo plugin? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Answer (score 1):

I would use the scrollTo plugin as suggested in another answer post (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). you can write a simple function that calls the scrollto method. Then, use the .NET ScriptManager to call that function at an appropriate point during the processing of the update panel

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will have a look into it =)